# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a service like below

```
    return this._http
    .post('/app/php/reports.php', data.toString(), 
     {headers:        this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

I am converting my code from normal JS to angular. It is working fine with normal ajax call. But I coulnt post using angular2. Can somebody please suggest me, why its not calling .php

imported things are

```
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

header is defined below

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

If I click the URL in in console error it download the php file. That means URL is correct.

Comment: which error you are getting and where ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 he gets 404 error as mentioned in question heading

Comment: you are getting 404 means with angular 2 request API is not accessible. check and compare your URL with normal and angular 2 request. May be you are missing any header or any other setting

Comment: just check your URl again.

Comment: Checked.. I can download that php file using that url

Comment: Can any body suggest me.. please

Answer (score 16):

If you are using the `InMemoryWeApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)` in your 'app.module.ts' @NgModule imports, try changing it to:

`InMemoryWeApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true})`

> **Pass thru to a live XHRBackend**
>   If an existing, running remote server should handle requests for
>   collections that are not in the in-memory database, set
>   *Config.passThruUnknownUrl: true*. This service will forward
>   unrecognized requests via a base version of the Angular XHRBackend.
>   https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#pass-thru-to-a-live-xhrbackend

```
app.module.ts
... 

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api

import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:  [
    ...
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true}), // fake in memory API simulation
  ],
  ...
```